# lumen http error 500 in nginx and how to see error_log?

Tags: php, laravel, http, nginx, lumen

my php project with lumen is ok on my computer with  **WAMP** (windows.apache.mysql.php) environment.

but when i upload it to my server on with  **LNMP** (Linux,nginx,mysql,php) environment,

i enter the URL , it came to  **HTTP ERROR 500**

the root is

```
/home/wwwroot/www.projectname.cn/projectname/public;
```

So i put a test.php at "/home/wwwroot/www.projectname.cn/projectname/public"

enter www.projectname.cn/test.php

it's the right page.

so i change the index.php

```
<?php
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
dump($app);
//$app->run();
```

also is **HTTP ERROR 500**

and at local environment , i add a route in **projectname/app/Http/routes.php**

```
<?php
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    return $app->welcome();
});

$app->get('/hello', function() {
    return "hello ";
});
```

i enter **“www.projectname.cn/hello”** it also doesn't work

the routes.php doesn't work

**what's maybe the reason caused that ??**

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error log dynamically using the command

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

This is the default nginx configuration in Debian/Ubuntu, so you could have to change error.log route.

Comment: thx，i add “catch_workers_output = yes”    in    “/usr/local/php/etc/php-fpm.conf” ，then can see the log